# If $a\lt{b}$ and $c\le{d}$, prove that $a+c\lt b+d$

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

> If $a\lt{b}$ and $c\le{d}$, prove that $a+c\lt b+d$.

This seems like a basic proof and I think this is how it goes:
$$c \le d, \text{ Given }$$
$$a+c \le a+d$$
$$a+c \lt b+d, \text{ since } a \lt b$$

Is that all I need? I'm thinking this does it all quickly and concisely, but I have had trouble with proofs in my classes.

Comment: Yes, or just go $a < b \implies a+c<b+c$, so since $c \leq d \implies b + c \leq b + d$, we have $a+c < b+c \leq b+d$, i.e. $a+c < b+d$.

Comment: Is $(b+d)-(a+c)>0$?

Comment: I'd do it $(a-b)+(c-d)\lt 0$ but it's all the same in the end

Comment: What is the reason you did it your way, @Ryker, versus my way?  It is just semantical?  I've noticed that the things posted have a middle argument between a less than and a less than or equal to sign.  Is that preferred when proving to see the logical reason?

Comment: Also, @Ryker, I like your proof, can you make that an answer so I can give you credit?

Comment: I just tried to make it more explicit in terms of how the logic goes. Your proof is fine, as well, and also uses three steps, but in a different way (for example, you implicitly derive the first inequality by using the fact that for any $a$, $c \leq d \implies a+c \leq a+d$). I do feel, however, that it's sometimes worth writing "trivial" stuff out explicitly, so that you are _sure_ you understand every single detail.

Comment: The real and shortest proof is obtained by eye-balling the title for 2 seconds.

Comment: @Dror, while it might seem trivial to you, I assume that Faffi-doo is just beginning to learn proofs. I think that in this setting it's extremely important he writes out all of the steps and all of the assumptions used in them. If he starts brushing or glossing over certain steps at the very beginning, then this could spell trouble later on. Plus, the question only seems trivial when you can implicitly account for all the steps in an instant, which perhaps not everyone does.

Comment: @Dror, it's not that I didn't like your answer, (i upvoted it), i just thought that Ryker's seemed like it was a little more of what I was looking for.  Thank you for your help.

Comment: @Faffi-doo , guys, wow! :) Perhaps I should have added a smiley in the end of the comment to avoid misunderstandings.. 1. You don't need to be so apologetic! :) Choose what is most correct for you. Always, and not just in Math. 2. I will not hold anything against you *even* if you actually did not like my answer.

Comment: @Ryker I very much belive the whole forum gathered in the question *knows* that this exercise is not going to sharpen your pencil too much. Iv'e seen Faffi-doo's questions around. I think Proving Cauchy–Schwarz inequality and triangle inequality in a normed vector space are things you should attempt. if you have, I'll give you more. Your pencil will have Bohr radius at It's tip in no time :-)

Answer (score 5, accepted):

We have that for any $c$: 
$$a<b \implies a+c<b+c$$
And for any $b$:
$$c\leq d \implies b+c \leq b+d$$.

Hence: $a+c < b+c \leq b+d$, that is: 
$$a+c < b+d$$.

Answer (score 4):

$$(a < b) \land (c \leq d) \iff a-b < 0 \leq d - c \implies a-b<d-c  \iff  a+c < b + d$$