# Proof that sum of two inequalities (with same direction of the sign) holds for positive numbers

Tags: inequality, proof-verification

I am sure this is a duplicate, but sometimes a question is so basic and silly that it gets ignored / deleted by experts so a newbie to the community is missing basic information because "everyone knows that" (I think this is some famous paradox but this is another topic)

The question is dead simple.

I assume that this is true:

**Given:**

$$a,b,c,d\geq0$$ 
$$a \leq b$$
$$c \leq d$$

**Then:** $$a+c \leq b+d$$

(and vice versa if we switch the sign direction between a and b, c and d)

E.g. the summation of inequalities with the same sign direction involving only positive real numbers does not change the direction of the sign)

Can you please help me find the proof for it?

**Here is my attempt:**

Let's convert it to equalities.

$$a \leq b \Rightarrow a + s_1 = b, s_1 \geq 0$$

$$c \leq d \Rightarrow c + s_2 = d, s_2 \geq 0$$

Let's sum the two equalities

$$a + c+ (s_1 + s_2) = b + d$$

And remove the slack variables (as they are both positive) to get

$$a + c \leq b + d$$

Well, I might have accidentally managed to answer my own question, but I'll keep it and rephrase it as - is this proof correct? Is there another known proof I can reference (instead of referencing my own answer...)

Comment: Your proof is correct.

Comment: Related: http://math.stackexchange.com/questions/679947/if-a-ltb-and-c-led-prove-that-ac-lt-bd?rq=1

Answer (score 1):

Your proof is correct. It is one of the easiest ways of approaching the question—Mr Prof